# NPM install gets Stuck and gives error (reason: connect ENETUNREACH)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

when I run NPM install it get stuck for a moment on idealTree buildDeps and gives this error
Is anyone else facing this issue??

```
    npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH

    npm ERR! syscall connect
    npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
    
    npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, 
    reason: connect ENETUNREACH
```

LOGS BELOW

```
 47 verbose type system
 48 verbose stack FetchError: request to 
 https://registry.npmjs.org/registry.npmjs.org failed, reason: 
 connect ENETUNREACH 
 48 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
48 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
48 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:490:9)
48 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
48 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
48 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
48 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections 
(node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

I tried [GITHUB](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4163#issuecomment-1010037450)

1. Clearing Cache npm cache clear --force
2. npm config set registry registry.npmjs.org --global
3. then deleting package-lock.json and then running npm install
4. npm install registry.npmjs.org (This gives the same error)
5. Deleting npm config delete http_proxy / https_proxy
6. Clearing Cache npm cache clear --force
7. Also im not using proxy or on vpn

I Found a work around of this... When i connect with my mobile Data it works fine but not with my WIFI and it stopped working suddenly.

CONFIG LIST:

```
; "global" config from /usr/local/etc/npmrc

; registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/" ; overridden by user

; "user" config from/xyz/.npmrc

registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/" 

; "project" config from /Documents/xyz_api/.npmrc

legacy-peer-deps = true 

; "cli" config from command line options

location = "project" 

; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; node version = v19.4.0
; npm local prefix = /Documents/xyz_api
; npm version = 9.2.0
; cwd = /Documents/xyz_api
; HOME = /home/xyz
```

Comment: Try entering the registry URL directly on a browser, if it doesn't work, maybe a  DNS flush?? not sure.

Comment: Also, your 4th step needs the full URL, in this case would be something like:
`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/registry.npmjs`

Comment: Please your config list of npm `npm config list`

Comment: @AissaouiAhmed have updated config list at the bottom of the post

Comment: `sudo npm config set maxsockets=5` [Ref](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3078#issuecomment-1228344292)

Comment: @AissaouiAhmed No it not working.. and Also, I found one more workaround if I disable IPV6 it works
If I keep using IPV6 disabled can it become a security issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, This happen in node 18 not happen on 16.
Then I just uninstalled 18 and installed 16 using nvm.

```
nvm uninstall 18
nvm install 16
nvm alias default 16
```

Answer (score 0):

> I Found a work around of this... When i connect with my mobile Data it works fine but not with my WIFI and it stopped working suddenly.

This sticks out to me, I ran into a similar issue a day after being able to install dependencies without problems, while working on MacOS (M1/M2 chip) - apparently the hardware was configured to the option "Automatically" for IPv6 which is essential for your device conntection to the internet.

I switched from "Automatically" to  "Link-local only" in my Network > TCP/IP configuration.

This issue is not specific to MacOS but any devices which may connect via IPv6

[I describe the issue more closely here](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/z9hsdw/npm_install_stuck_on_idealtree_builddeps/)

Answer (score 0):

That's because node uses IPV6 addresses by default. You network probably doesn't support IPV6.